# Infer a type within a type from an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
type operation = 'create' | 'update' | 'delete';

type mutationKey = {
  operation: operation;
  id: K extends 'delete' | 'update' ? string : undefined; // want this field to be undefined if operation above is 'create'
}

// example 1
const ex1 = {
  operation: "create"
}

// example 2
const ex2 = {
  operation: "update",
  id: "1"
}
```

Is there a way for me to type the `id` field when I add `operation: "create"` or any other operations in the object conditionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) between all existing operations. This way it's easily extensible to add other operations.

```js
interface CreateOperation {
  operation: 'create'
}


interface UpdateOperation {
  operation: 'update'
  id: string
}

interface DeleteOperation {
  operation: 'delete'
  id: string
}

type Operation =
  | CreateOperation
  | UpdateOperation
  | DeleteOperation

// example 1
const ex1: Operation = {
  operation: 'create',
}

// example 2
const ex2: Operation = {
  operation: 'update',
  id: "1"
}
```

Comment: thank you, this what I wanted and going to mark it as a solution as it's a good practice to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) for this behavior.

```
type Operation = 'create' | 'update' | 'delete';

type mutationKey<O extends Operation> = {
    [K in O extends 'create' ? never : 'id']: string;
} & { operation: O };

const ex1: mutationKey<'update'> = { operation: 'update', id: '1' };
const ex2: mutationKey<'create'> = { operation: 'create', id: '2' };
//                                                        ~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ operation: "create"; id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'mutationKey<"create">'.
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'mutationKey<"create">'.
```

Comment: I had tried this approach, but the way I am trying. I can't pass a generic to mutationKey. But thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a union of both cases.

```
type Operation = 'create' | 'update' | 'delete';

type MutationKey = {
  operation: 'create';
  id?: undefined; 
} | {
  operation: Exclude<Operation, "create">
  id: string
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYBLA9gOygXigcgGN4JkI8oAffAVzABNTyq86IAbCYMgbgFgAoAaEhQAstWDJ0GANIQQOKAG8BUKGgRTMALnxESXPH35qUdAPy7qGVgDMUGCHW5QBAX0rLV6zah1QAUQAPAjZqVgAeOAgkPwwAGigAIn1SJIA%20bzNdAGdgeAcAc3cBAQB6MqgIIMQAWzAOKABGAQJMPKqgpt1xSTi5BVwVEx8YrQxdFOI0ksF%20Cs66hugAJlb24E6VnolxgcVhtQ0xuMnaBi4k%20Ky6Saak9yA)

Comment: thank you, this is a cleaner approach to @lepsch's solution.